# DatagramSocket, посылаю несколько DatagramPacket с разными портами

Tags: java, сокет, udp

Создаю сокет в одном("главном") потоке.

```
DatagramSocket socket = DatagramSocket();
```

Затем запускается один в поток, в конструктором которому передается ссылка на сокет. Поток крутится и слушает любые ответы. Другой поток создается только для отправки запроса.

Если в *DatagramPacket* использовать один и тот же порт - все работает замечательно. Но мне надо посылать запросы в другую сторону с тремя разными портами. В этом случае я не получаю ответа на с других портов, только на первый.

Означает ли это, что мне надо использовать три сокета для разных портов? Что я не так понимаю в работе с сокетами?

Демонстрационный псевдокод:

```
class A{        
    public void main(String[] args) {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        HandlerMy handler = new HandlerMy()
        C c = new C(handler,socket)
        с.start();
        B b = new B(socket);
        b.start();
    }

    class HandlerMy extends Handler {           
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Messaga msg){
            System.out.println(msg.obj)
        }

    }
}

class B extends Thread {
    privat Socket socket;

    public B(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void  run() {
        try {
            DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagrammPacket({0,2,3},3,InetAddress.getHostByName("localhost"),1026);
            DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagrammPacket({0,2,3},3,InetAddress.getHostByName("localhost"),1027);
            socket.send(packet1);
            socket.send(packet2);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }

    }
}


class C extends Thread {

    private Handler handler;
    private Socket socket;

    public C(Handler handler,Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void  run() {
        try {
            while(!isInterupted{
                byte[] buffer = new buffer[1024];
                buffer[0]=-1;
                DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagrammPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                socket.receive(packet1)

                 handler.sendMessage(
                            Message.obtain(
                                    handler,
                                    0,
                                   buffer[0]))
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Сделал подобие "пула" сокетов, после *DatagramSocket.receivet(DatagramPacket)* поток повисает, кто-нибудь знает в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Кусочки кода бы, а то не особо понятно... или поподробнее опиши схему сети и абонентов с портами и адресами (пусть даже вымышленными)

Comment: если вы ждете ответов на разных портах, то должны быть разные сокеты, которые слушают на каждом порту